# How to check if a Blender subprocess is still running in background mode from a Python script?

Tags: python, scripting

I have run a blender instance in the background using `subprocess.Popen`.
Now I want one panel to get visible only if there is a blender instance running in the background.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a general Python question, not specific to Blender.

Comment: True, when recommending to ask here I wasn't aware this was about subprocesses.

Answer (score 1):

This is no different from regular subprocess use:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html

Use the return value of `Popen` and check it will [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll)

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057794 - though in your case you won't want to wait until poll finished.